# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user ''@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, datasource, tomcat6, mysql-error-1045

I have been trying to set up a DatabaseConnectionPool for a web app for the last couple of days with no success. I have read the relevant sections of the Tomcat docs and a great deal around the subject and think I'm doing everything right, but obviously not because I keep on getting the following error:

```
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES))
```

I'm not getting the error when I start Tomcat running, but when I try to run the following servlet:

```
package twittersearch.web;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import twittersearch.model.*;
public class ConPoolTest extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response) 
                  throws IOException, ServletException {
        Context ctx = null;
        DataSource ds = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/twittersearchdb");
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            if(conn != null) {
                System.out.println("have a connection from the pool");
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(conn!=null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The context for the webapp is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>

    <!-- Configure a JDBC DataSource for the user database -->
 <Resource name="jdbc/twittersearchdb" 
           type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
     auth="Container" 
     user="root" 
     password="mypwd" 
     driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/twitter" 
     maxActive="8" 
     maxIdle="4"/>


</Context>
```

What I really don't understand is why the error isn't saying that the access is denied to 'root'@'localhost' when I've specified that that's the user.

What I've tried:

Do I have a duplicate context.xml? No. I deleted the default on in Tomcat 6.0/conf. I tried putting a context.xml in [mywebappname]/META-INF/context.xml but not only did this not work, but resulted in the creation of a file named TwitterSearch.xml which was autogenerated and put in the Tomcat 6.0/conf/Catalina/localhost directory. So now I'm just editing that one and thats the only one I have.

Is it the version of Tomcat? Well, I completely reinstalled the latest version of Tomcat 6.0 so I don't think it's that.

Are we missing some jars? I have the tomcat-dbcp.jar, jconnector.jar and all the other ones that I think I'm meant to have in the Tomcat 6.0/lib directory.

When I look at the passwords in the MySQL  database they seem to have been coded for security purposes into a long alpha-numeric string. Is this normal? Should I have this in my context.xml or just the normal password?

I really don't know how I can sort this out and would really appreciate  some expert advice.

Many thanks in advance.

Joe

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your setup looks fine. This looks to purly be a permissions problem.

You need to grant that user access in mysql. While Java will connect to localhost, it will do so using tcp/ip - however in mysql localhost and 127.0.0.1 have different meaning. Issuing this SQL should do the trick.

```
grant all on twitter.* to 'root'@'127.0.0.1' identified by 'mypwd';
```

That assumes Java resolves 'localhost' to 127.0.0.1, if things still doesn't work, you could try changing your connection string to "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/twitter"

> Should I have this in my context.xml
>   or just the normal password?

As you have it now, the plaintext password.

Comment: Hi nos, Thanks for your reply. I played around with the GRANT ALL statement you supplied. For some reason the only thing that works is when I;

Comment: GRANT ALL on twitter.* TO ''@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypwd';

Comment: I have deleted the root user so that the only user is ''@'localhost' and it works. While I'm happy that it's working, something is still not right because I have specified in my apps context.xml that the user is 'root' so I'm wondering why '' will work and in fact the error message that I was getting beforee was always denying access to ''@'localhost' and not 'root'@'localhost'. Do you have any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: @Joe Did you find out why user name is not being used in the error message? I want to try the grant command but do not want to delete root user or something like it..

Answer (score 4):

In your configuration context.xml for the webapp you have to change user="root" by username="root"

Answer (score 0):

In my case (MySql v.5.7) I got this error due to creation of the user via GRANT command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO myuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Using CREATE command instead, resolved the above error:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO myuser@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Hope it'll helps somebody