# Spring JDBC Connection failed! Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

> **ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot
> create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user
> 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))**
>
> WARN :
> org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext -
> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> **Error**
> creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/dao-context.xml]: Invocation of
> init method failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC
> Connection for DDL execution ERROR:
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization
> failed

```
JDBC Connection properties file

jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password= 1234
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/estore
```

mysql grant follow picture

[image]

My spring web project is not running by MySQL Access deny Error

Please Help me

Comment: check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782197/cannot-create-poolableconnectionfactory-access-denied-for-user-localhost

Comment: You should not give any application root access to a database.  Create a credential just for that app and restrict access to only those things that pertain to the application.

Comment: @duffymo
I tried to use different user
but same error caused
what's problem?